# Does html, head, or body have limitations for their height or does grid have limitations in repeat?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a Ul tag with the css as below

```
.tempUl{
   display: grid; 
   grid-gap: 5px; 
   grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill ,minmax(400px, 2fr)); 
   grid-auto-rows: 5px;
}
```

I am trying to make a 2 columned infinite scroll ul.
Untill the height of html, body, div(.container) reaches 10262px, the li tags are well positioned. However, although i have put any limitations to those tags, grid ends at a certain point.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

so, this answer kind of leads to another question but this is still my answer.
[image: grid track limits]

if there is a limit to grid rows or columns, does this mean that creating an infinite scroll using grid is not possible?